# How can I embed a PowerPoint presentation into a WPF application without opening another window?

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, integration, powerpoint

Currently I have a WPF application in C#, but I'm finding it to be incredibly difficult to find any useful ways to embed a PowerPoint presentation into my window.

One solution I found here: [Embedding a Powerpoint show into a C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360758/embedding-a-powerpoint-show-into-a-c-sharp-application)

This solution created the problem of having PowerPoint run in another window, but just display its UI within the WPF application. This meant that when the WPF window was focused, the PowerPoint presentation was not, and stopped playing. There was also the problem of PowerPoint crashing when the window was closed.

Another solution I found was here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/118676/Embedding-PowerPoint-presentation-player-into-a-WP

The solution was popular, but I found it difficult to work with. I don't know any Win32 programming, OR C++, so I found it extremely hard to modify. I managed to get it to stop displaying a second copy of the PowerPoint (an intended function in the original project), but I've not yet found a way to automatically open the PowerPoint presentation.

So what I need is a way to cleanly open the PowerPoint presentation automatically and in the background (I don't want the PowerPoint UI to be displayed at any point), and to allow it to run automatically (and not respond to input) while the application is running. It would be wonderful if I could keep it within C# and WPF, and not have to deal with Win32 and C++.

Is this possible? At this point I'm really regretting this project simply because of the PowerPoint integration headaches.

Comment: Yet another way is converting your presentation to another format, like a video, which can be played with WPF MediaPlayer. This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311579/

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll look into that.

Comment: @Joulukuusi Your solution was the one that worked best for us. Please create an answer so that I can give you the bounty.

Comment: Done, however, I don't have Office 2010, so I can't test the solution. If it doesn't work for you, I guess you could answer your own question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could convert your presentation to a video format on-the-fly:

```
// not tested as I don't have the Office 2010, but should work
private string GetVideoFromPpt(string filename)
{
    var app = new PowerPoint.Application();
    var presentation = app.Presentations.Open(filename, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse);

    var wmvfile = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".wmv";
    var fullpath = Path.GetTempPath() + filename;

    try
    {
        presentation.CreateVideo(wmvfile);
        presentation.SaveCopyAs(fullpath, PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsWMV, MsoTriState.msoCTrue);
    }
    catch (COMException ex)
    {
        wmvfile = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        app.Quit();
    }

    return wmvfile;
}
```

And then you would play it with `MediaElement`:

```
<MediaElement Name="player" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" />

public void PlayPresentation(string filename)
{
    var wmvfile = GetVideoFromPpt(filename);
    player.Source = new Uri(wmvfile);
    player.Play();
}
```

Don't forget to `File.Delete(wmvfile)` when you're done playing the video!

Comment: As long as you don't need user interaction for your presentation, this is a pretty decent solution.

Comment: the SaveCopyAs will take a long time, any method to get signal when the video file is ready, because I want play that video after it is ready.

Answer (score 3):

Launching the presentation via the command line with the /s flag will play the slideshow without launching the splash screen.

```
powerpnt.exe /s c:\path\to\your\presentation.pptx
```

I would try that in concert with some of the WPF embed solutions you've mentioned or taking a look at [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610924/wpf-opening-up-exe-program-within-wpf-window).

I know little about WPF, so hopefully someone can provide a better answer incorporating all these pieces.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really like it, and I'm not sure this applies to your situation. You would need to have access to the presentation, so much's for sure. It *is* rather easy and leightweight however.

My basic idea was to somehow embed the powerpoint presentation in html and just use the webbrowser control to display it. There seems to be a [number of ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855/embed-a-powerpoint-presentation-into-html) to do that.

I decided to try and save the presentation directly as html, which turned out to be possible (at least for PP2010), albeit the layout could be nicer. Another approach (e.g. the google docs) might produce something nicer. I took the following from this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980553/en-us).

- In PowerPoint 2010, open the presentation that you want to export to
  HTML
- Press Alt+F11.
- Press Ctrl+G.
- In the Immediate pane, type the following, and then press Enter:
  `ActivePresentation.SaveAs "<Drive>:\users\<username>\desktop\<filename>.htm", ppSaveAsHTML, msoFalse`

  **Note** To save by using the Single File Web Page (*.mht; *.mhtml) file format, replace htm at the end of the file name with **mht**, and replace ppSaveAsHTML with **ppSaveAsWebArchive**.

If you export it in htm, you get a lot of additional files, in mht it's just a single file so that suited me better. I'm pretty sure it would also be possible to automate this step in code if you need to go generic with your solution.

To display the html file in a webbrowser control is the easy part, I uploaded it to my dropbox for convenience and just set the source (I'll leave it up there for a few days if you want to have a look at it directly).

As for starting the slideshow immediately, I'll have to look into it some more.

```xml
<WebBrowser x:Name="webbrowser" Source="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/27614341/test.mht"/>
```

[image]

Comment: When displaying a PowerPoint presentation in a WebBrowser, how do I access information like number of slides?

Comment: Oh, never mind. I now realise the `Slide 1 of 3` part is added during the conversion to html.

Answer (score 1):

There is a WPF control called `DocumentViewer`.

1. First the pptx should be converted to .xps file format.
2. Then Bind it to the `Document` property of the DocumentViewer.

[Here](http://www.uhlme.ch/convert_office_to_xps) is the link to convert office documents (including `pptx`) to XPS in C sharp.

XAML

```
<DocumentViewer Name="myDocumentViewer" Margin="0,0,0,59">

</DocumentViewer>
```

Bind to the `Document` property of the control (Note that `ConvertPptxDocToXPSDoc` is the method to convert pptx to xps)

```
 myDocumentViewer.Document = this.ConvertPptxDocToXPSDoc(this.FileName, this.newXPSDocumentName).GetFixedDocumentSequence();
```

Comment: This won't work if the presentation has sounds, but otherwise it's a good idea.

Comment: Have you look at following posts?  [post1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11432875/873979)
[post2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/118676/Embedding-PowerPoint-presentation-player-into-a-WP)