# WPF add User Control depending on configuration

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to build a  set of User Control Elements like a PDF Viewer or just a "Note" with data from a Database refreshing every 5 minutes. Depending on a Configuration (Data/ContentTemplate?), when the program starts, it adds a User Control and put it on a position of the screen. Are there any example projects I can see how I could solve it?

The result app should open over 3 screens/windows and shows a dashboard with information we could change. Problem also is, for one control we have a Chart with 1000px width, so just use grids and put it in there is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to implemented something like a PDF viewer from scratch, check if FlowDocument can fit your needs first.

You can put the big controls in a ScrollViewer so it can fit in a smaller space, provided that scrolling is acceptable behavior.

Comment: So far we thought about one page at a time, with a timer that changes the page after x seconds. So scrolling should be avoided. But that is not a technical challange, the source is a power point presentation. Maybe i use a Mediaplayer for that like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725908/how-can-i-embed-a-powerpoint-presentation-into-a-wpf-application-without-opening , so the user dont have to export it to something else.